# booting 64 bit ubuntu 15.10 into 32 bit x86 architecture windows 10

Tags: boot

how can I install Ubuntu 15.10 of 64 bit into 32 bit processor of x86 architecture? Because I have a 32 bit windows 10 in x86 architecture and I want to use Ubuntu now. So can I install 64 bit Ubuntu on my laptop?

Comment: And why not download the 32bit iso of Ubuntu?

Comment: @xangua 64 bit processes data faster than 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not install a 64 bit OS in a 32bit architecture machine. Either real install or a virtual machine.

Comment: even if it has x86 architecture??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86